What's the meaning of this last part of the hadith: Then he placed his right hand on his left hand, wrist, and forearm,
Assalamu alaikum. What's the meaning of this last part of the hadith: 'Then he placed his right hand on his left hand, wrist, and forearm,' or 'Then he placed his right hand on the back of his left hand, wrist, and forearm.' Or 'He would place his right hand over the back of his left hand, wrist, and forearm, and he told his companions to do likewise.' Does it mean on the back of his left forearm at the end of the elbow, or is it only the little part after the wrist? What about placing it on the full forearm before the elbow ends? And what is Sheikh Al Albani's view on this? Asalamu alaikum.
